# dont work "input tap x y" with external app

Tags: android, android-activity, input, su

Try to make my app tapping on right places on some apps. I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec() with "input tap x y" adb shell command, but it working only on my activity. What can i do to make it work?

```
Thread r;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button BtnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    r = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                synchronized (this){
                    sleep(10000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e){

            }
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input tap 120 1050");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    View.OnClickListener StartClick = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StartApp("some.app.here");
            r.start();
        }
    };
    BtnStart.setOnClickListener(StartClick);

}

public void StartApp(String AppName){
    Intent LaunchApp = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(AppName);
    if (LaunchApp != null) {
        startActivity(LaunchApp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a way like:

```
 try {
               dataOutputStream.writeBytes(command + "\n");
               dataOutputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Where "command" some command with "su" preveosly